# Node.js auto migrations

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js

I have been doing Django for several years and was spoiled by their automigrations that they have supported for a very long time. Recently I started using SailsJS (which I am very new to) and noticed that it only supports `alter` for db migrations in development, NOT production. Is there any third party for node that does something to that effect? I looked at knex but that doesn't autodetect the changes made to my models. I'm looking for something similar to what Django has.

I read the below thoroughly:

https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/model-settings#?migrate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeORM does this with `{sync: true}` setting. It also supports JS projects. What I like about it is that it does only safe automigrations, it adds columns and tables, but never drops them. So, 90% of migrations are automatic, you only need to be explicit about unsafe operations and create migrations manually.

Answer (score 1):

The only framework that has such functionality is the [nestjs](https://nestjs.com). The only downside it that it is not a pure js solution. It is typescript. But the functionality is heavily inspired in ORM frameworks like Django ORM.

Answer (score 1):

In development you can use `alter` settings for your models, it works perfectly fine. But doing auto migrations in production is a bad idea, you don't want to risk loosing any data. It's better to do migrations through some process that includes declaring migrations and rollbacks as well as keep a record of what migrations where ran already. Sequelize ORM has migrations so the frameworks that work with it will have them too, i.e. Actionhero.js. There is also Nodal.js not as popupar but has migrations inbuild. In Sails.js I usually just introduce migrations for the DB I'm using, for MySQL I'd just install and use [mysql-migrations](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql-migrations) for Postgres [postgres-migrations](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postgres-migrations) etc.